# Changing Woocommerce New Order "From" email address to customer email

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I’m just after some coding help with a Woocommerce tweak a client needs on their Wordpress site. We have a Woocommerce site that has just been set up as an enquiry system. When the customer places an order, the client gets a normal New Order notification by email.

However, we need the format of that email to be modified so that when the client get that email, they can reply to their customer's email address, not their own site's email address that was set in Woocommerce. (As it is normally, they would have to either forward it or copy/paste the contents of that email into a fresh email and put in the customers email address manually in order to respond.) They don’t want to have to do that.

How can I achieve this

many thanks in advance!

cheers,
Kurt

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and managed to get this done by following this two tutorials:

http://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/

http://web.peterhartree.co.uk/2014/woocommerce-change-reply-field/

Hopefully this helps.

Regards, Christian

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the links for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will only you to update the reply-to header for the New Order email:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_header', 'spigot_reply_to_mail_filter', 11, 3);


function spigot_reply_to_mail_filter($headers = '', $ordertype = 'new_order', $order = '') {

    if(!is_object($order) || empty($order) || $ordertype !== 'new_order') { return $headers; }

    $name = $order->get_billing_first_name().' '.$order->get_billing_last_name();
    $email = $order->get_billing_email();

    if(is_array($headers)) {
        $headers['Reply-To'] = "{$name} <{$email}>";
    } else {
        $headers .= "Reply-To: {$name} <{$email}>\r\n";
    }
    return $headers;
}
```

credit goes to: https://spigotdesign.com/change-woocommerce-new-order-reply-address-customer/